# Преобразование данных в series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, после парсинга сайта, объект Series получил данные в таком формате

```
296         Чемпионат Украины. Высшая лига           Университет Старый Луцк - Говерла (с ОТ)  09.03 12:45   [82:76 (26:23,18:20,11:14,27:19)]
297         Чемпионат Украины. Первая лига  Днепр-3 ДВУФК-СДЮСШОР-5 - Университет Харьков ...  09.03 12:00   [84:75 (27:17,27:22,16:23,14:13)]
298                    Чемпионат Финляндии                     Нокия - Каухайоен Карху (с ОТ)  09.03 19:30   [63:87 (17:23,18:16,15:27,13:21)]
299                         Чемпионат Чили         Универсидад Католика - Пуэнто-Альто (с ОТ)  09.03 00:00   [72:81 (23:22,13:21,10:16,26:22)]
300                         Чемпионат Чили       АБ Темуко - Универсидад де Консепсьон (с ОТ)  09.03 01:00  [86:100 (15:24,26:30,23:24,22:22)]
301                         Чемпионат Чили                      АБА Анкуд - Лас-Анимас (с ОТ)  09.03 02:00   [65:76 (19:15,17:14,18:20,11:27)]
302                         Чемпионат Чили        Депортес Кастро - Атлетико ПТО Варас (с ОТ)  09.03 02:00   [80:76 (17:16,23:16,19:20,21:24)]
303                         Чемпионат Чили       Депортиво Вальдивия - ЦЕБ Пуэрто-Монт (с ОТ)  09.03 02:00   [79:84 (28:23,15:14,23:23,13:24)]
304         Чемпионат Южной Кореи. Женщины   Шинхан Сибёрдз (жен) - Кеб Ханабанк (жен) (с ОТ)  09.03 13:00   [79:84 (19:22,15:22,18:24,27:16)]
```

Пробовал преобразовать данные, .split, int(), str(). Всегда выдает ошибку SyntaxError, указывая на первое ":". Подскажите, как можно преобразовать данные, чтобы над ними можно было работать (значения в () в отдельную series, и сравнивать их).

```
url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/results/getmain'
params = {'showAll': 'true', 'date': '2020-03-09'}
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
r = response.json() 
score =[]
basket = r['results'][1]['Elems']                   
for i in basket:
    for j in i['Elems']:
        score.append(j)     
with open('response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(score, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
df = pd.read_json('response.json')
basketball = df[['champName', 'nameGame', 'date', 'scores']
print(basketball.scores)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, с которым у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: приведите часть кода, где вы парсили данные. Какой тип данных у элементов списков (если это списки, а не строки)?

Comment: dtype; Object. Я только новичок в python, прочитал, что есть возможность реализации через регулярные выражения, но получается только по отдельности каждое число вывести ['79', '84', '19', '22', '15', '22', '18', '24', '27', '16'].

Comment: Жаль, не могу прочитать данные с этого сайта -`"This website is not available in your country."` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['[2453:0 (2453:0)]','[0:0 (0:0)]','[103:112 (25:27,28:22,28:36,22:27)]',
'[107:120 (29:36,34:35,21:27,23:22)]', '[86:100 (15:24,26:30,23:24,22:22)]',
'[65:76 (19:15,17:14,18:20,11:27)]', '[80:76 (17:16,23:16,19:20,21:24)]',
'[79:84 (28:23,15:14,23:23,13:24)]','[79:84 (19:22,15:22,18:24,27:16)]']
s = pd.Series(a)
```

s, соответственно, получается:

```
0                      [2453:0 (2453:0)]
1                            [0:0 (0:0)]
2    [103:112 (25:27,28:22,28:36,22:27)]
3    [107:120 (29:36,34:35,21:27,23:22)]
4     [86:100 (15:24,26:30,23:24,22:22)]
5      [65:76 (19:15,17:14,18:20,11:27)]
6      [80:76 (17:16,23:16,19:20,21:24)]
7      [79:84 (28:23,15:14,23:23,13:24)]
8      [79:84 (19:22,15:22,18:24,27:16)]
dtype: object
```

Дальше:

```
res = s.str.extract(r'\((.+?)\)')
```

res - датафрейм с нужными вам данными:

```
                         0
0                   2453:0
1                      0:0
2  25:27,28:22,28:36,22:27
3  29:36,34:35,21:27,23:22
4  15:24,26:30,23:24,22:22
5  19:15,17:14,18:20,11:27
6  17:16,23:16,19:20,21:24
7  28:23,15:14,23:23,13:24
8  19:22,15:22,18:24,27:16
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Если нужно разбить и эту серию на интервалы, тогда добавьте:

```
res = res[0].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

тогда res будет

```
        0      1      2      3
0  2453:0   None   None   None
1     0:0   None   None   None
2   25:27  28:22  28:36  22:27
3   29:36  34:35  21:27  23:22
4   15:24  26:30  23:24  22:22
5   19:15  17:14  18:20  11:27
6   17:16  23:16  19:20  21:24
7   28:23  15:14  23:23  13:24
8   19:22  15:22  18:24  27:16
```

**UPDATE**

После уточнения условий:

```
res = s.str.extract(r'^\[(?P<общий_итог>\S+?)\s\((.+?)\)')
res = pd.concat([res['общий_итог'], res[1].str.split(",", expand=True)], axis=1)

def make_eq(a: str) -> str:
    if a is not None:
        num = [int(x) for x in a.split(':')]
        sign='<' if num[1] > num[0] else '>'
        return f"{num[0]}{sign}{num[1]}"
    return None

res[[0,1,2,3]] = res[[0,1,2,3]].applymap(make_eq)
```

Тогда res получится:

```
  общий_итог       0      1      2      3
0     2453:0  2453>0   None   None   None
1        0:0     0>0   None   None   None
2    103:112   25<27  28>22  28<36  22<27
3    107:120   29<36  34<35  21<27  23>22
4     86:100   15<24  26<30  23<24  22>22
5      65:76   19>15  17>14  18<20  11<27
6      80:76   17>16  23>16  19<20  21<24
7      79:84   28>23  15>14  23>23  13<24
8      79:84   19<22  15<22  18<24  27>16
```

Comment: 0
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
..   ...
300  NaN
301  NaN
302  NaN
303  NaN
304  NaN вот такой вывод

Comment: В переменную `a` я скопировал данные из вашего вопроса. Важно, что серия s - аналогична вашим исходным данным.

Comment: да, спасибо, с этим разобрался. Но вывод res почему то отличается, один столбец только

Comment: В чем может быть проблема, выводится один столбец? И как добавить столбец с общим результатом?

Comment: Вы можете привести полученный датафрейм, чтобы нам не пришлось самим быть выкачивать данные с сайта? И точнее опишите, что вы хотите получить. Общий результат  вы хотите получить из исходного фрейма или посчитать самому?

Comment: Нужно общий результат вывести в отдельный столбец, а где результаты отдельно по каждой четверти, как то сравнивать между собой значения. Т.е. например 19:22, что 19<22, найти максимальное и минимальные значения.

Comment: Общий итог вывести не проблема. мне не понятно вот что: есть ячейка "19:22" - что нужно из нее вывести? результат какой? меньшее значение, большее значение или что? покажите пример итогового вывода.

Comment: Мне надо каждый столбец отфильтровать, где первое > второго или наоборот. И так для каждого столбца. Есть какой нибудь способ, чтобы можно было сравнивать значения в каждой ячейке?

Comment: Опять "25"! Как отфильтровать? покажите желаемый результат хотя бы на одной строке вашего фрейма.

Comment: (19:15,17:14,18:20,11:27), в первом 19>15, второе 17>14, третье 18>20, четвертый 11<27. По этим условиям фильтруется вся таблица. Это например. то есть вариаций очень много.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, но все равно так и не понял, что требуется получить и как вы собираетесь фильтровать таблицу...

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Фильтровать думаю так, условие, которое вы написали, для проставления знаков '<' '>'. применить отдельно для каждого столбца res[[0, 1, 2, 3]], то есть например, чтобы таблица выдала только результаты, где res[0] '<', res[1] '>', res[2] '=', res[3] '<'

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.